# How to check the order of elements in cypress based on data attributes

Tags: javascript, cypress

Let say i have a parent div with the id of "container" and it has 4 children with specific data attribute named "data-test", how do i check if each children is in the right order? let say the right order should be the following:

1. black-leather
2. emerald-stone
3. diamond-blade
4. fire-sword

[image]

in my test i have something like

```
it('Should have the specific order...., ()=>{
  cy.get('#container').should('exist')
    .contains( .. not sure what to put here )
})
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML showing the `data-test` of all the four child elements?

Comment: @AlapanDas not sure why the html code didn't show but i updated it with a picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute selectors require square brackets, and they don't "have.text" instead you must invoke the `.attr()` method to get the attribute value.

```js
cy.get('#container [data-test]').eq(0)
  .invoke('attr', 'data-test').should('eq', 'diamond-blade')

cy.get('#container [data-test]').eq(1)
  .invoke('attr', 'data-test').should('eq', 'fire-sword')

cy.get('#container [data-test]').eq(2)
  .invoke('attr', 'data-test').should('eq', 'emerald-stone')

cy.get('#container [data-test]').eq(3)
  .invoke('attr', 'data-test').should('eq', 'black-leather')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. The `eq` will assert that the position of the expected texts:

```js
cy.get('#container').within(() => {
  cy.get('data-test').eq(0).should('have.text', 'black-leather')
  cy.get('data-test').eq(1).should('have.text', 'emerald-stone')
  cy.get('data-test').eq(2).should('have.text', 'diamond-blade')
  cy.get('data-test').eq(3).should('have.text', 'fire-sword')
})
```

You can also apply an loop as well:

```js
var texts = ['black-leather', 'emerald-stone', 'diamond-blade', 'fire-sword']
cy.get('#container').within(() => {
  cy.get('data-test').each(($ele, index) => {
    expect($ele.text().trim()).to.equal(texts[index])
  })
})
```

Comment: Whoah this is neat! im gonna try both versions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the data, sort it, and store into a variable. If your app, has a sorting method, use it then extract the data and check it against the stored sorted variable.

Here is an example using innerText.

```
cy.get("#container [data-testid]")
  .then(($el) => {
    // use lodash .map() to get innerText of each element
    // then sort the array
    return Cypress._.map($el, "innerText").sort();
  })
  .then(cy.log)
  .as("sortedArray");

cy.get("#sortable").should("be.visible").click();

cy.get("@sortedArray").then((sortedArray) => {
  cy.get("#container [data-testid]")
    .then(($el) => {
      // use lodash .map() to get innerText of each element
      // then sort the array
      return Cypress._.map($el, "innerText").sort();
    })
    .then(cy.log)
    .should("deep.equal", sortedArray);
});
```

Here is a working similar [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/checkSortedColumn.md).